# MySQL Error on creating tables

Tags: mysql

I am quite new at SQL. I have created a file full of complete table requests, all are working except one. The error relates to the ProductPrice foreign Key in the Orders_Info table. I can not see or find what I have done wrong. Anyone able to help give me a pointer please?

```
Create table Orders
(
Order_Number INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Date Date, Account_Number INT(11),
FOREIGN KEY (Account_Number) REFERENCES User_Accounts(Account_Number) ON   DELETE CASCADE,
Address_ID INT(11),
FOREIGN KEY (Address_ID) REFERENCES Address_Book(Address_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Order_Status VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Order_Number)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

Create table Order_Info
(
Order_Number INT (11),
FOREIGN KEY (Order_Number) REFERENCES Orders(Order_Number) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Product_Number INT (11),
FOREIGN KEY (Product_Number) REFERENCES Products(Product_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
Product_Quantity INT (11), ProductPrice Decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ProductPrice) REFERENCES Products(ProductPrice) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Post (add to your question) the exact error message.

Comment: Error Message - MySQL said:  
#1005 - Can't create table 'Cake_Test.Order_Info' (errno: 150)

Comment: When do you create your Products table?  Post ([edit]) its schema.

Comment: Your FK to the ProductPrice column is a little strange. Why is a row in Order_Info related to every row in Products that happens to have the same price? Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail what you are trying to do, and to show the definition of your Products table.

Comment: A foreign key should not reference a not unique column. While MySQL allows that, I didn't see a real world use case yet. And the behaviour is "undefined".

Comment: The products table is already created prior to these tables:

Comment: CREATE table Products
     (
    Product_ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Category_ID INT(11), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Category_ID) REFERENCES Categories(Category_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Product_Name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, ProductDescription   VARCHAR(300), ProductImage VARCHAR(53),
    ProductPrice Decimal(10,2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Product_ID)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;